# Porting KVM (Written for Linux) to Mac OS X

Tags: macos, kvm

I am trying to port KVM (Written for Linux) to Mac OS X.

---

**Background work :** I started going through Apple Developer Documents which lists out a procedure to do just that. I was not able to understand some parts of it, and the ones I understood and tried did not work well (as planned). 
As Apple Developer documents suggested, I also tried through fink, macports etc., But, these package management applications come into picture once the code is successfully compiled on the host, right? (Thats what I assumed). *Correct me if I am wrong. 
Right now, I am engaged in removing the errors faced, one by one. This method is taking painstakingly long amounts of time and effort, and also, I do not know, if this will ever work.

---

**QUESTION :** Please let me know whether my approach is right or wrong. If right, let me know what should be my next step. If wrong, let me know what should be my first step. 
**P.S :** Lots of the time allocated for the project has already gone in vain of trying different methods. Please help me in taking a definitive way to solve this problem.

Comment: Found this bit of info with an install update you might find helpful - http://blog.itsux.com/2015/06/kvm-install-in-os-x-on-mac.html

Comment: @JeffClayton That's a different "kvm" than the question was asking about. It's a .NET version manager, which has since been renamed to "dnvm". It didn't exist yet when this question was asked, and has no relation to Linux KVM virtualization.

Comment: Hmm, interesting - did not know there was another kvm for linux out there in the past than the major one for virtualization. Thanks for the update. The question has little to no information about the product, just a desire to convert one linux app to a version for a non-linux architecture.

Answer (score 30):

Your approach is incorrect.

KVM is inherently an extremely OS-specific application. Porting it to Mac OS X is not simply a matter of going through the code and fixing compile errors — significant parts of it will need to be rewritten entirely to work on OS X. (Just for starters, for instance, there is no `/dev/kvm` on OS X. VT support works in a completely different way.)

If any of this is news to you, **TURN BACK NOW**. KVM is not a simple piece of software. If you do not first understand what you are dealing with, you will not be able to port it, no matter how much time you spend on it.

Comment: duskwuff, I doubt you got where you are today by taking advice such as "TURN BACK NOW."

Comment: @Zectbumo Banging your head against a wall (by trying to port a highly system-dependent application to another platform by fixing compile errors) is neither productive, nor a particularly educational exercise. Even if the goal is learning, rather than the end result, there's an important distinction between taking on *ambitious* tasks and *infeasible* ones.

Comment: would you care to answer the rest of the question: "If wrong, let me know what should be my first step." or is "TURN BACK NOW" still your final answer?

Comment: @Zectbumo Yes, that is my answer. No amount of blindly throwing oneself at the problem will get this job done. "Spend the next five to ten years learning more about C programming, the x86 architecture, KVM, and Mac OS X systems programming" might qualify, but I suspect it's a rather larger answer than the asker had in mind.

Comment: @Zectbumo Note that this is taking into account the context of the other Stack Overflow questions from this user — I don't mean this as a slight to them, but their other questions indicated that they were a beginning C programmer. They simply didn't have the necessary knowledge to even *begin* to approach this task… it's as if a man walked into a hardware store and asked for instructions on how to build a skyscraper.

Answer (score 1):

kvm for windows is available now.
see : https://github.com/fanwenyi0529/fvm
fvm is a cross-platfrom kvm, it can run on windows & linux host, porting to mac is similar to windows.

Comment: that answer (as of writing), has a broken link maybe it should be https://github.com/fanwenyi0529/qemu-fvm